# Bluetooth headset always receiving audio, even when none is playing

Tags: audio, bluetooth, google-chrome, headphones

I have a Bluetooth headset (MPOW-059) that I use to listen to audio on my Macbook Pro. In the past few months, I've noticed something odd - it always seems to be receiving an audio signal from the laptop, even when no audio is playing.

Normally, when I play audio, I can hear a very faint static hiss start right as I start the audio, and it typically stops within a few seconds of stopping audio (this is probably the normal thermal noise you get with most speakers and headsets). But now, the static never stops after stopping audio, and the hiss continues perpetually unless I disconnect the headset. Muting my system volume does not help.

A typical case for this is when watching a Youtube video in Chrome. The video ends and I navigate away from it (or even close the tab) but I can still hear that my laptop is sending a signal to the headset. This also only happens after audio plays, never before (such as when I pair my headset in the morning - I don't hear the hiss until I've actually played audio).

This wouldn't really be a problem except that it's draining my headset battery. I only experience this behavior on my Macbook, not on any other device I pair my headset with.

How do I determine what is sending the audio signal to my headset, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Did you check under System Preferences -> Audio for which is the default audio output? Default audio output can be sending audio to your device, if it is set there as default, even if you have another audio settings for some specific app. Multiple output is possible under MacOS. I suggest you change the default output to internal speakers, and then configure youtube to send to your headphone when needed. Or something like that for other apps.